# Is there a method that would be called right before the serialization of the object in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine

There is a class that have data that cannot be serialized easily. But, I can prepare it to serializable form. 
So, is there any method to override that will be called right before serialization to prepare data?

```
[System.Serializable]
public MyCalss {
    //Unity can serialise this list;
    public List<int> serializableData;

    //class contains a lot of data that cannot be serialized by Unity3D

    protected override void OnSerialize() { // <-- looking for this method
         //pack all my data into the serializableData array
    }
}

public Behaviour: MonoBehaviour {
    MyClass instanceOfMyClass; // will be serialized by Unity3D
}
```

Comment: What serialization mechanism/library are you using?

Comment: Default serialization of Unity3D

Comment: Unity has no serialization of its own that I'm aware of, other than `OnNetworkSerialize`...  Could you give a code example?

Comment: I've added example of the code I expect

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft ???  The power of Unity's UI is based on [serialization](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2012/10/25/unity-serialization/).  Yarg, your example method states it will pack data in to an array, serialization should take care of that for you automatically so it's not clear why you need a pre-serialization pass.

Comment: @Jerdak: The serialization listed there is handled by the .Net framework, not Unity.  That's why I was confused.

Comment: [`OnValidate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html) will be called on a MonoBehaviour if it is edited via the default inspector. If you've written a [custom inspector](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Editor.html), you could manually watch for changes and re-serialize at that time. If you're using properties, the setter could call some hooks.

Comment: @Jerdak I have non-serializable data, like a LinkedList (Unity does not serialize them) or pathfinding graph (with links to other nodes) or whatever. It can be flattened into simple List, but it's to expensive doing it on every data change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void OnBeforeSerialize()
void OnAfterDeserialize()
```

they exists in interface

```
ISerializationCallbackReceiver
```

so just implement this interface is ok

Answer (score 0):

If you want a .Net solution (as opposed to [afpro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25440449/276648) which is Unity specific), you can also use [OnSerializingAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.onserializingattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[Serializable]
public MyCalss {
    //Unity can serialise this list;
    public List<int> serializableData;

    //class contains a lot of data that cannot be serialized by Unity3D

    [OnSerializing]
    internal void OnSerializingMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        //pack all my data into the serializableData array
    }
}
```

Similarly to `OnSerializing` you also have `OnSerialized`, `OnDeserializing` and `OnDeserialized` attributes. They all require a method taking a `StreamingContext` as argument.